# Dynamic height cells with a jerky scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I know this is quite a hot topic answered in several places but no answer yet solved my problem. I'm working on an app with a main tableview with multiple cell types (table can be up to hundreds of cells), each one has a different potential height, depends on its content. I'm trying to rely more on dynamic cell heights, calculated by the system when drawing the cell but my scrolling is badly affected when i'm trying to scroll to the bottom of the table.

I understand the estimated height of a cell should be really close to what it is eventually, but there is no way to do that unless I manually calculate the size of each cell by summing up all of its texts, images, constraints and so on... That pretty much knocks the edge out of using dynamic cell heights, doesn't it?

The best solution i've found online is caching up the real cell heights on "cellWillDisplay", but it only works after all cells are presented at least once. 
Thing is, when my app loads, it automatically scrolls to bottom without animation so "cellWillDisplay" isn't called for all cells above.

This is my estimatedHeightForRow snippet:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let object = self.fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) as? Object {
        if let objectID = object.objectIDPermanentString {
            if let savedHeight = self.rowsHeights[objectID] {
                return savedHeight
            }
        }
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

This is my cellForRow method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: object.id, for: indexPath)
    self.configureCell(cell: cell, object: object)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: add cellForRowAtIndexPath method in questions .

Comment: added cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: also add configureCell .

Comment: Basically what it does is entering data for each cell type. Putting the texts in the labels, image in imageviews and so on... That's it.

Comment: yes but how to render image in imageview.

Comment: I don't set anything about rendering the image in the image view. Could you explain what you have in mind?